# Problem in binding a listbox to data

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a table that have these fields: `ID , Name`

I have bound a listbox to the table.

My question is, when the user has selected an item in listbox, how would I find out what the ID of the selected item is?

Note: The id is not equal to the selectedindex or id of items in items list

Comment: Please put the code by which you are binding your ListBox?

Comment: please post some appropriate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g.

Suppose you have a DataTable dt, with columns ID and Name in it.
then while binding include the following code,

```
this.listbox.DataSource = dt;
this.listbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.listbox.ValueMember = "ID";
```

while reading the selected values of listbox,

`this.listbox.SelectedItem` will give u the selected Name and

`this.listbox.SelectedValue` will give u the corresponding ID

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
lst.SelectedItem.Value;
```

OR

```
lst.SelectedValue;
```

where lst is a ListBox Cotrol

Answer (score 0):

What type of application is this? ASP.net, Windows Forms, WPF?

I have a feeling you are working with Windows Forms, as the other two are much clearer...

Here is some code for a Windows Forms App... Basically, you create your own class, and use that for the list items. The list box will display the results of the ToString() method, so override that to get the value you wanna display. When you access ListBox.SelectedItem, it will be an instance of the class you defined, and you can access whatever properties are necessary:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyListItem item1 = new MyListItem("Java", 1);
        MyListItem item2 = new MyListItem("C#", 221);
        MyListItem item3 = new MyListItem("C++", 13);

        listBox1.Items.Add(item1);
        listBox1.Items.Add(item2);
        listBox1.Items.Add(item3);
    }

    private class MyListItem
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public MyListItem(string name, int id)
        {
            this.ItemName = name;
            this.ItemId = id;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.ItemName;
        }
    }


    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyListItem selectedItem = (MyListItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Name is: {0}, Id is: {1}", selectedItem.ItemName, selectedItem.ItemId));
    }
}
```